# Understanding AWS VPCs and Subnets

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-vpc, subnet

Go easy on me as I'm new to software development, but I've been tasked with creating an application that is hosted in an s3 bucket and is authenticated using cognito. When a user signs in they should redirected to a homepage which contains the users previous login times, these times are stored in a dynamodb database.

What I do understand about vpcs is that it gives you a private piece of the aws cloud for your resources, and subnets divide that piece into public (accessible by the internet) and private subnets (not accessible by the internet).

Now whats not clear to me is which AWS resources fall under a vpc and what resources should you put under a private subnet and which should you put under a public subnet. I've attached an image of a architecural solution to my application and would like some feedback on it if possible.

[image]

Comment: VPC subnets only apply to services which get allocated network interfaces. That excludes S3 and cognito.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to start with a few AWS tutorials such as:

- [Serverless Web Application with Cognito, API Gateway, S3, and Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/serverless/build-a-web-app/)
- [Build a Serverless Web Application with Amplify](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/build-serverless-web-app-lambda-apigateway-s3-dynamodb-cognito/)

In your situation, there's no need to deploy into VPC. You're not currently using any private resources (such as a MySQL database) that would need to be in VPC.

S3, API Gateway, Cognito, and DynamoDB are all AWS services. They don't run in your VPC (if you had a VPC). A VPC-hosted application could create [private VPC endpoints](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/privatelink/vpc-endpoints.html) to these services (except Cognito) but that's a relatively sophisticated use case that's not needed here, given the information available in your question.